# schema registry + what is the correction when _schema topic became corrupted

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-schema-registry

we have 3 kafka machines

each kafka machine have the following services

1. schema-registry service
2. kafka service
3. zookeeper service

we are suspect that the schema topic `_schema`  became corrupted on all 3 nodes

since Schema Registry stores a versioned history of all schemas , and Kafka is used as Schema Registry storage backend , then the operation of all 3 kafka nodes also damaged

what should be the fix for this scenario ?

maybe the option is ( but we not sure )

stop /start the `Kafka + schema registry + zookeeper`

Comment: Why do you suspect that the `__schemas` topic became corrupted?

Comment: we installed the schema-registry again on all nodes , and since then we faced some problems

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: for example - failed deserialized messages AND 
scheme not found

Comment: or - OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions

Comment: All those need to be addressed separately. The first two are client exceptions, not necessarily errors with the topic (try upgrading the client versions). Is the registry reporting offsets out of range, or clients? The schemas topic should be compacted, and it always is read from the beginning on restart of the registry, so it should never be out of range. If it's clients, then you are storing consumer group information for longer than the retention policy of the user's topics.

Comment: what you mean about - try upgrading the client versions? , second do you think restart all services as kafka / zookeeper / schema , will help here?

Comment: For example, let's say you've imported avro serializer 3.3.0, have you tried upgrading to 5.3.1, or whatever the latest version is? You can restart, sure, but that won't fix client exceptions about deserialization or offsets out of range